# Read very slow from a database

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot with spring data jpa, hibernate and oracle.

Actually, I my table I have arount 10 millions of record, I need to do some operation, write info to a file and after delete the record.

It's a basic sql query

```
select * from zzz where  status = 2;
```

I done a test without doing operation and delete record

```
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int page = 0;
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, LIMIT);

    Page<Billing> pageBilling = billingRepository.findAllByStatus(pageable);

    while (true) {
        for (Billing: pageBilling .getContent()) {
            //process
            //write to file
            //delete element
        }

        if (!pageBilling .hasNext()) {
            break;
        }

        pageable = pageBilling .nextPageable();
        pageBilling = billingRepository.findAllByStatus(pageable);

    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long microseconds = (end - start) / 1000;
    System.out.println(microseconds + " to write");
```

Result it's bad, with a limit of 10 000, that took 157 minutes, with 100 000 28 minutes, with millions 19 minutes.

It's there a better solution to increase performance?

Answer (score 0):

The following are likely to improve the performance significantly:

1. You should not iterate past the first page. Instead, delete the processed data and select the first page again. Actually you don't need a page for that you can encode the limit in the method name. Selecting late pages is rather inefficient.
2. The process of loading, processing and deleting one batch of items should be in a separate transaction. Otherwise the `EntityManager` will hold all the entities ever loaded which will make things really slow.

If that still isn't sufficient yet you may look into the following:

3. Inspect the SQL executed. Does it look sensible?  If not consider switching to `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` with a `query` method that takes a `RowCallbackHandler` you should be able to load and process all rows with a single select statement and at the end to process one delete statement to remove all rows. This requires that the status that you use for filtering does not change in the mean time.
4. How do the execution plans look like? If they seem of inspect your indices.

Comment: the time took don't include writing file and delete entity. There are only  a check in the where to know the status...  Cost of the query in sql developper, show 96.30. A table acess(full) is done.